# How to change position of h3 text

Tags: css

I have this HTML and CSS:

```css
@media(max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  cfa-text {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  .cfa- text {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  body.cfa-text {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  .col-v. sm-9 {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  .h3 {
    margin-left: 200px! Important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <h3 class="cfa-text"> "Professional, thorough, diligent<br /><br /> Excellent, my flat looked brand new after they had finished. Still can't get over those sparkling taps. Thanks to Nico and the team for a job well done."
  </h3>
</div>
```

I would like the text to be in the centre of the page. At the moment is sits to the left slightly in desktop view.

Comment: can you explain what you exactly want?

Comment: The text is left of centre at the moment in desktop view and i want it to be in the centre of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `text-sm-left text-md-center`  bootstrap classes to `h3`. hope this is what you are looking for. thanks

```css
(max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  cfa-text {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

(max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  .cfa-text {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

(max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  body.cfa-text {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

(max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  .col-sm-9 {
    margin-left: 20px! Important;
  }
}

(max-width: 1920) and (min-width: 769) {
  .h3 {
    margin-left: 200px! Important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <h3 class="cfa-text text-sm-left text-md-center"> "Professional, thorough, diligent<br /><br /> Excellent, my flat looked brand new after they had finished. Still can't get over those sparkling taps. Thanks to Nico and the team for a job well done."
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it. No pure css fix though?

Comment: but you have used bootstrap classes that is why i used bootstrap classes.. you don't want to use bootstrap?

Comment: I didn't write it. It's wordpress

Comment: Don't mind. If css is better but I'm sure your solution works.